# Cannot find module "mysql"

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have this issue with my ubuntu 14.04 server, when I try to start js file with node.

```
module.js:340
throw err;

`Error: Cannot find module 'mysql'
at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
at require (module.js:380:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (etc\site\site.js)
at Module._compile (module.js:456:26)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:474:10)
at Module.load (module.js:356:32)
at Function.Module._load (module.js:312:12)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:497:10)
```

I have tried to install

```
npm install mysql -g
npm install node-mysql -g
```

But I still get this error.

How I should fix this?

Comment: Do not install modules you use in your project globally (`-g`). Node by default only searches in the `node_modules` directory of your project. Go to your project directory, and  install `mysql` using `npm install mysql`  without the `-g`. The `-g` option should only be used if you install some `cli` applications.

Comment: I have done that without -g but no help

Answer (score 2):

Goto your project folder and run `npm install`

Answer (score 1):

I have same error, just run

```
npm install
```

will fix the problem.

When I install some other new package with --save

```
    npm install xxx package --save
```

mysql package was deleted, missing, not sure why.

just run 'npm install' will fix everything.

Answer (score 0):

First, you should use `npm install mysql node-mysql --save` if you haven't, and then run `npm install`.

If it doesn't work, this error is probably coming because your module is not installed in the right directory. I suggest you try the following:

Check is your module is actually installed like that:

```
./node_modules/node-mysql/node_modules/
```

If so, just move them all to :

```
mv ./node_modules/node-mysql/node_modules/* ./node_modules/
```

If not, please show us your node_modules directory.